# Python equivalent to "find -type f"

Tags: python, file, search, python-3.x, recursion

What would be the equivalent in Python 3 to the bash command `find -type f`?

```
find /etc/ -type f
```

would generate a list that looks something like this:

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf
/etc/request-key.d/cifs.idmap.conf
/etc/request-key.d/id_resolver.conf
/etc/issue
/etc/maven/maven2-depmap.xml
/etc/gtkmathview/gtkmathview.conf.xml
/etc/fstab
/etc/machine-id
/etc/rpmlint/mingw-rpmlint.config
/etc/rpmlint/config
/etc/cupshelpers/preferreddrivers.xml
/etc/pulse/system.pa
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf
/etc/brltty.conf
/etc/numad.conf
...
```

How would I (in Python 3) get a list of all *files* (excluding directories) recursively under a specified path? I also want the heading of the paths to mirror the entered path. For example, if I had (while being in /etc) ran `find . -type f` I would have gotten a list like:

```
./rsyslog.conf
./request-key.d/cifs.idmap.conf
...
```

The difference being **/etc/**... vs **./**...

Comment: I believe `glob` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and then look at each of the files checking the "type" with [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile).  That should get you pretty close...

```
import os
import os.path

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/directory'):
    for f in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root, f)
        if os.path.isfile(fname):
            print fname  # or do something else with it...
```

I'm not sure where you were going with the `/etc` vs. `./` stuff in your question, but I suspect that if this isn't what you want, then you'll just need to do something like

```
os.path.relpath(fname, '/path/to/directory')
```

to get the relative path that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute system command in python using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
output=subprocess.check_output(['find /etc/ -type f'])
print output
```

or using commands module:

```
import commands
output=commands.getstatusoutput('find /etc/ -type f')
```